# Dynamically query on a Table in EF Core based on Controller Name

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core for the project(.Net Core 5) and for authorization I need to get clientId from Database.I need to call Set() to query on different table to get clientId.I using the following code:

```cs
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var routeId = context.RouteData.Values["Id"];
    string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var type = _context.Model.FindEntityType("ProjectName.Model.DatabaseModel."+controller).ClrType;

    if (req.Method == "DELETE")
    {
        //injected DB context
        var data = _dbContext.Set<type>().FindAsync(routeid);
    } 
}
```

DBContext class:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
  {
    public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<XXX> XXXs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AAA> AAAs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BBB> BBBs { get; set; }
```

and finally DataBase model class:

```
    [Table("xxx")]
    [Index(nameof(ClientId), Name = "Index_2")]
    public class XXX
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("clientId")]
        [StringLength(45)]
        public string clientId { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the type from the Controller Name but getting the error as **'type is a variable but used as a type'**

Comment: Well, it is possible, but what you want as data? object? What to do later with this object?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv from data I Want to extract the clientId.So basically later in the code I can access like data.ClientId

Comment: Class `ProjectName.Model.DatabaseModel.XXX` has base class, with property `Clientd`?

Comment: Yes correct.so every controller has a separate table in the db and they all have clientId in it.So the aim is to get clientId from db for that table using the Id coming from queryparams in Delete request and use that to Authorize the request.

Answer (score 0):

We can create the following extension method for retrieving `ClientId`:

```cs
public static class RouteHelper
{
    private static MethodInfo _getClientIdGeneric = typeof(RouteHelper).GetMethod(nameof(GetClientIdGeneric), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    private static Task<string?> GetClientIdGeneric<T>(DbContext context, int routeId)
        where T : class
    {
        var param = Expression.Paramater(typeof(T), "e");

        var filter = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "Id"), Expression.Constant(routeId));
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filter, param);

        var selectBdy = Expression.Property(param, "clientId");
        var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(selectBdy, param);

        return context.Set<T>().Where(filterLambda).Select(selectLambda).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public static Task<string?> GetClientIdAsync(DbContext context, string entityType, int routeId)
    {
        var et = context.Model.FindEntityType(entityType);
        if (et == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var genericMethod = _getClientIdGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(et.ClrType);
        var result = (Task<string>)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { context, routeId })!;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your authorization:

```cs
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var routeId = context.RouteData.Values["Id"];
    string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

    if (req.Method == "DELETE")
    {
        var clientId = await RouteHelper.GetClientIdAsync(_context, "ProjectName.Model.DatabaseModel." + controller, routeId);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I haven't explained the issue properly. In your answer, there is a class RouteBase, but in my case there is no class like that from which I can get the type.Controller Name matches Database model names inside DB context.Hence idea is to get the instance of the model class and query for clientId.I am editing my question

Comment: Basically I have a controller name as string from RouteData(HttpContext).and using that I have to get type of the database model class as the Model class name and controller name is exactly same

Comment: Ok, will update answer according to new details.